# Difference between "advance for" and "advance by"

Tags: british-english

He is advanced for his years.
The visit of viru has been advanced by two days .

Answer (score 0):

This sentence, "he is advanced for his years", I think it means that he is very young. Btw, advanced in age/years means that someone is old and lived for many years.

Answer (score 0):

These two have quite different meanings. "He is advanced for his years" means that he is more developed in some way (such as how much he knows, his physical development etc.) than would be expected at his age. A visit being "advanced by two days" means that someone has organized for the visit to happen two days earlier than originally planned.

So in the first sense, "advanced" means *developed*, whereas in the second sense it means *brought forward*.